# Extra line around Polygon

Tags: graphics

I produce a polygon as follows:

```
pts = {{2.986, 3.129}, {-4.549, 2.226}, {2.812, 
    0.8372}, {-4.583, -1.871}, {5.278, -2.288}, {-0.6944, -1.42}, \
{4.688, 1.184}, {-2.222, 2.157}};
grTemp = 
 Graphics[{{FaceForm[], Rectangle[{-6, -4}, {6, 4}]}, Opacity@.5, 
   EdgeForm[], 
   Polygon@Table[
     BSplineFunction[AppendTo[pts, pts[[1]]], SplineDegree -> 4][
      x], {x, 0, 1, .0025}]}]
Export["temp.pdf", grTemp]
Export["temp.png", grTemp]
```

On the screen, the polygon looks fine. However, when I export it to PDF, it obtains an interior outline, which I do not want. If I export it to PNG, then the interior outline does not appear, so I cannot upload the bad picture. As you can see, I tried to add `EdgeForm[]` to get rid of the outline, but that did nothing. I would very much appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Per your request, I made a screen capture of a detail of the PDF after enlargement, you the the line along the edge. And unfortunately, the suggestion of `Edgeform[Opacity@.5]` did not fix the problem. Screen capture of PDF detail; it has the offending line going around it:

[image]

Comment: Please post the errant image.

Comment: `grTemp = Graphics[{{FaceForm[White], Rectangle[{-6, -4}, {6, 4}]}, 
   Opacity@0.5, EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.5]], 
   Polygon@Table[
     BSplineFunction[AppendTo[pts, pts[[1]]], SplineDegree -> 4][
      x], {x, 0, 1, .0025}]}]`

Comment: @Syed Thanks for trying, but it did not work.

Comment: Version and operating system? (Works fine on 13.3 on Mac ARM)

Comment: Works on MMA 13.3 Windows.